# Visual Studio Update Paused - Now cannot be resumed, modified or removed

Tags: visual-studio

First of all, I am trying to open a support request with Microsoft about this issue, but their support reporting portal isn't working. I have resorted to Stackoverflow because I have no way of getting to Microsoft.

[image: Support Ticketing system does not work]

Yesterday, I started updating Visual Studio 2022 from Visual Studio Installer by mistake and paused it shortly after. Today, I tried to open a project but Visual Studio seemed unavailable. At that point I remembered about the paused update and re-opened the Visual Studio installer. I tried to Resume, and I got the below error. The Modify and Remove options give out the same error too. **There is no Repair option.**

> Sorry something went wrong
>
> The dependent package of
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord,version=17.1.33203.90,productarch=x64'
> cannot be found: Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerClient.Concord,
> version=[17.0,18.0].

[image: Update Error]

I also tried Restarting and deleting temporary files using the Disk Cleanup tool - no difference.

I have tried to force an uninstall from the Add or Remove programs but this still redirects me to the Visual Studio installer.

I have tried to research this error online but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not fix the issue but at least I managed to uninstall the Visual Studio instance to be able to start from scratch again. If you do not want to go down the route of uninstalling, feel free to try the steps as suggested by @garbagecollector.

1. I deleted the installation folder for 2022 from ProgramFiles.
2. I deleted the Visual Studio installer from Add or Remove programs. (Note: This actually uninstalled a working version of Visual Studio 2019 that I had, and left the messed up version of 2022 with the same issues, so beware if you do not want to uninstall another working version of Visual Studio)
3. Then I ran InstallCleanup.exe via CMD (in admin mode). Refer to the "Remove All with InstallCleanup.exe" section within this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). This seems to have cleared all Visual Studio related files including the Visual Studio
   installer, and I could re-download the installer for Visual Studio
   2022 Community edition and start afresh.

Comment: I followed a simplified approach by : 1) deleting the installation folder for 2022 from Program files 2) running InstallCleanup.exe on the specific version of 2022 I wanted to remove 3) re-installing 2022 from the Visual Studio Installer.

This saved me from re-installing the Visual Studio Installer and a version of VS 2019 I had additionnally.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today and could solve it by removing corresponding dependencies from `_package.json` files from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\[PACKAGE_NAME]` folders.

I am not sure whether you can repair your installation this way, I tried only with uninstall.

So in your case edit this file:
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord,version=17.1.33203.90,productarch=x64` and remove the line marked with "-->" under "dependencies":

```
{
    "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord",
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        --> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerClient.Concord": "[17.0,18.0]"
    }
}
```

In my case I had to repeat this procedure for three or four `_package.json` files.

Comment: thank you for taking your time to post this. Coincidentally I had just fixed it. I deleted the installation folder from Program files. Then tried to uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio Installer from Add or Remove Programs (this deleted my working version of Visual Studio - I had 2019, and left the broken 2022 with the same issues). At the end I ran InstallCleanup.exe from CMD, which seems to have solved the issue and cleared all VS related files.

Comment: Seems not helping, the installer will show more errors, such as Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Remote

Comment: @Lamp, that is why I said one would need to repeat the process for every found dependency.